# Ubuntu 20.04 stuck on installation. Laptop had fallen before

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel, hard-drive, hardware

My laptop fell down from about 3 ft. Ubuntu was running at the time. I restarted but Ubuntu froze on "Kernel Panic"
I was able to start windows 10.
Did a hardware check with Lenovo vantage and it showed that everything was good.
I wanted to reinstall ubuntu. Already had it on usb so started the process.
Chose to replace the installed Ubuntu os.
The first time I got stuck for 30 mins during installation.
(Now grub loader is gone too. )
Quit the installer. Opened "disk". It showed hard disk may have some problems.
Ran smartctl. It says disk may fail within 24 hours.

The windows os worked fine.
I can't access my files to get a backup.
Can anyone help me figure out what might have happened and what I can do now?

Edit: "Hard disk may fail within 24 hours" it says. Will get it replaced.
Thanks

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  There is no such release. Ubuntu uses *yy.mm* format (year.month of release) for all server & desktop releases, the *yy* being used only for IoT and specialist appliance/devices releases than can use *snap* packages only. Specialist releases are usually used headless, so I'd recommend a desktop release and not a device release (ie. *yy.mm* format release and not *yy* based).

Comment: I would of course check what you're trying to install, and then assuming it's not a fake, verify the ISO is correct, and the write to your install media was flawless.  Possibly useful : https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck (*this is automatic on recent media; 20.04 & later.. but you've only specified a non-existent release so adjust for what you're using*)

Comment: 20.04 it's the same version I had before. It worked fine. No problems with the iso.

Comment: Please correct (ie. though edit) your question to reflect 20.04. Ubuntu 20 reads like a Ubuntu Core 20 or other *snap* based release, which is a different product to a *yy.mm* release such as Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: running hard drives tend not to react too well to being dropped maybe the hard drive is damaged?

Answer (score 0):

no problem dude just use some linux file reader on windows 10 to backup your data and then delete the ubuntu partition using windows disk management and then reinstall ubuntu using the free space obtained...
when i was installing kubuntu i nearly killed my laptop thrice nut now its been two months and everything is beautiful
dont panic it often happens
make sure you have proper installation file in usb